# Eclipse Ant build task generating OutOfMemoryError - after several successful builds

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, ant, out-of-memory

Created headless build setup of projects in Eclipse workspace.

Basically this is how its working

- Eclipse workspace has the projects
- Via ant file

  - Clean, refresh, build the eclipse workspace using eclipse ant task
  - then run tasks to build jar

All working fine - except that the build via eclipse ant task - runs into OutOfMemoryError after about 50 such executions.

**NOTE**: Automated build keeps failing - until open Eclipse on that workspace and close.
Thereafter again runs fine for 50 builds, and then OutOfMemoryError.

Build workspace task in the Ant file

```
<target name="build_workspace">
    <echo message="building workspace" />
    <eclipse.incrementalBuild kind="full"/>
</target>
```

Also tried kind = clean and incremental separately but same error.

```
<target name="build_workspace">
    <echo message="building workspace" />
    <eclipse.incrementalBuild kind="clean"/>
    <eclipse.incrementalBuild kind="incremental"/>
</target>
```

Looks like something piling up in the workspace, that gets cleaned/corrected when open Eclipse on that workspace.

Kindly suggest some solution/pointers.

Here is how the build failure looks like-

```
build_workspace:
     [echo] building workspace

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\US\.jenkins\workspace\XBrowseReleaseBranchTests\testrunscripts\runtests.xml:51: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
    at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:344)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:710)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util.getExceptionSummary(Util.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ant.IncrementalBuild.execute(IncrementalBuild.java:75)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to increase maximum memory limit in Ant Configuration for JVM.
It can done by passing 
-Xmx1024m (If you want to set 1GB as limit) as VM argument in eclipse.
Here is one of way of doing this.
[image: Here is one way of setting this]

Comment: I already did that - before making this post/question. 
Increasing memory does not resolve the problem
There is surely something which is accumulating in Eclipse or Workspace - that results in this problem.... and which would need clearing/cleaning.... But not sure what or where I look for.